# plot() doesn't work on IPython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python scientific computing, and I tried to make a simple graph on IPython notebook.

```
import pandas
plot(arange(10))
```

Then error had shown as below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6b139d572bd6> in <module>()
      1 import pandas
----> 2 plot(arange(10))

NameError: name 'plot' is not defined
```

Instead, with IPython --pylab mode, a right graph popped up when I tried the same code.

Am I missing any environment?

My environment is Mac OSX 10.8.5, python 2.7.5, IPython 1.1.0, matplotlib 1.3.1, and pandas 0.12.0. I downloaded python scientific environment by Anaconda installer from continuum.io. Anaconda version is the newest one as of 1/30/2014.

Comment: Plotting example [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html#plotting-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not advisable to use `pylab` mode. See the following [post](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Carreau/posts/blob/master/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb?create=1) from [Matthias Bussonnier](https://twitter.com/Mbussonn)

A summary from that post:

Why not to use `pylab` flag:

1. It is irreversible- Cannot unimport
2. Unclear- if someone else did not run with this flag (or with a different setting of it) what would happen?
3. Pollutes the namespace
4. Replaces built-ins
5. Side effects

You are much better by doing the following inside your IPython notebook.

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
```

The following is the code which `--pylab` brings into the namespace

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pylab, mlab, pyplot
np = numpy
plt = pyplot

from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize, getfigs

from pylab import *
from numpy import *
```

---

Still, if you wish to use `pylab` and have plots inline, you may do either of the following:

From shell:

```
$ ipython notebook --pylab inline
```

Or, from within your notebook

```
%pylab inline
```

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` gives me a `ERROR: Magic function matplotlib not found`, both in `ipython qtconsole` and `ipython notebook`.

Comment: Check the following issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12

Comment: Should work if the IPython version is 1+. If you just run ipython on your shell- what version number does it show?

Comment: IPython 0.12.1 on Ubuntu 12.04, that might explain the error. Time for an upgrade, I guess. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: great..Till then you can work around with pylab as I have put in the answer above.